# Blender all texture images into one

Tags: blender

i want to export a blender model for my game, and it would be much easier to import it, when it contains only one texture image. Unfortunetaly there are 6 texture images. The question is: **How can i put all texture images into one image, so i don't have to re-map the textures?**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is "bake" the textures.

You turn on all of your textures, and then bake them on, which will produce an image texture that should contain everything.

Here are the controls:
[image]